# How to normalize a vector in pgf/tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a picture in pgf/tikz in which I define some vectors (coordinates) at the start. The picture changes depending on these initial coordinate positions. eg:\coordinate (A) at (3,4);

During the drawing, I need to normalize these vectors. How do I compute the corresponding vector that is a normalized version of A?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the `()!<length>!()` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\newcommand\normalize[2][(0,0)]{%
  \draw[red,->] #1 -- ($#1!1cm!#2$);}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\coordinate (a)  at (1,3);
\coordinate (b)  at (-2,5);
\coordinate (c)  at (-0.5,0-.5);
\draw[->,ultra thin] (0,0) -- (b);
\draw[->,ultra thin] (0,0) -- (a);
\draw[->,ultra thin] (a) -- (b);
\normalize{(a)};
\normalize{(b)};
\normalize{($(b)-(a)$)};
\normalize[(a)]{(b)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

`\normalize` has one mandatory argument, and an optional one. `\normalize{(x)}` will draw the normalized vector corresponding to `(x)`, from the origin. `\normalize[(y)]{(x)}` is the path from `(y)` to `(y)!1cm!(x)`; that is, the path that starts in `(y)` and goes `1cm` in the direction from `(y)` to `(x)`.

[image]

For visualization purposes, the original vectors are drawn thin and their normalized versions are red.

Comment: Nice. The hardcoded 1cm, however, should better be calculated from the actual x and y norm vector values, which might be different from 1cm.

Comment: @Daniel But then those would be direction dependent if say, `x=1,y=2` is given. So better to keep a uniform length for visualizations. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @percusse Yeah, but: The norm of `(<angle>:<distance>)` in any coordinate system is: `(<angle>:1)`. In fact, I have managed to write a simple `norm cs:` which does exactly that (but obviously intended for `(<x>,<y>)` coordinates). The problem is, though, to get that to work with coordinates/node’s anchors. I can’t find an easy way to calculate this `<angle>` without already falling back to the basic TeX coordinate system.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Sorry I can't see how that happens. In the case I've given, if the unit circle is an ellipse then it's not `(<angle>:1)` but actually an angle dependent `(<angle>:<r(angle)>)`. Actually it seems that it's not even nice visually to have dependent lengths for unit vectors.

Comment: What if instead of `1cm`, I want `1` of whatever unit my `axis cs` is using?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution with a `to path`. The first argument is the length of the offset. It defaults to 1cm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{offset/.style={to path={%
    -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1cm!(\tikztotarget)$)}},
         offset/.default=1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
   \draw[red,->]  (0,0) to[offset=2]   (100,0);
   \draw[blue,->] (0,0) to[offset]     (0,2);
   \draw[->]      (1,1) to[offset=1.5] (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three offset vectors]

Answer (score 7):

I have decided to create a custom coordinate system, `norm cs:`. The needed macros and two keys are packaged in the library `norm` (→ `\usetikzlibrary{norm}`).

#### Keys:

- `norm` is a `to path` (similar to the ones already discussed in other answers) that uses the `norm cs` to create an normalized vector.
- `Norm` can be used to change the length of the normalized vector.

  The default is `1` in the current coordinate system. This has the advantage that any change in the coordinate system (the `x` and `y` keys can be used to change the coordinate system) the normalized vector is still of the length of `1` (and not `1cm` in the paper plane which is used with in other answers).

  The key, though, can also be used to set a fixed length (in the paper plane) which is used then.

Without any change in the coordinate system and with the default `Norm=1` we get for Example 1

[image: Example 1 a]

With

```
x={(1.5cm,1cm)},
y={(-1.5cm,1cm)}
```

we get

[image: Example 1b]

instead of (`Norm=1cm`)

[image: Example 1c]

#### `norm cs:`

The `norm cs` accepts as parameter any TikZ `<coordinate>` and an optional `from <another coordinate>` (the `<another coordinate>` is by default `(0,0)`, the origin). This will result in the normalized (according to `Norm` setting) vector.

Note that this does not draw any lines in any relation to the current point on the path.

```
\draw (1,2) -- (norm cs: 3,0);
```

will result in a line from `(1,2)` to `(1,0)` and not `(2,2)` (case A) nor the point that is `1cm` from `(1,2)` to `(3,0)` (case B). The `norm cs` will most likely be used with relative coordinates. The following will draw a line from `(1,2)` to `(2,2)` (case A):

```
\draw (1,2) -- ++(norm cs: 3,0);
```

If one wants to specify the point that is `1cm` from `(1,2)` to `(33,0)` one needs to use the `from` parameter

```
\draw (1,2) -- ++(norm cs: 3,0 from 1,2);
```

or the `norm` `to path`:

```
\draw (1,2) to[norm] (3,0);
```

[image]

### Code

#### [`tikzlibrarynorm.code.tex`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarynorm.code.tex)

```
\tikzset{
    Norm/.code={%
        \pgfmathparse{#1}%
        \edef\qrr@tikz@norm{\pgfmathresult\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared pt\fi}%
        \let\ifqrr@tikz@normcs@unitsdeclared\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared},
    Norm=1,
    norm/.style={to path={-- ++(norm cs: \tikztotarget\space from \tikztostart)}}
}
\newif\ifqrr@tikz@normcs@unitsdeclared
\newdimen\qrr@pgf@normcs@from@x\newdimen\qrr@pgf@normcs@from@y
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{norm}{%
    \let\qrr@next\relax
    \pgfutil@in@{ from }{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@
        \qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@from#1\@qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@from
        \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@hard
    \else
        \qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@from#1 from +0pt,+0pt\@qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@from
    \fi
    \expandafter\qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@@to\expandafter{\qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@to}%
}
\def\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@easy#1{%
    \pgf@xx\@ne
    \pgf@yy\@ne
    \pgf@xy\z@
    \pgf@yx\z@
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#1)\relax
    \pgfmathatantwo{+\pgf@x}{+\pgf@y}%
}
\def\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@hard#1{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#1)\relax
    \pgf@xa\pgf@x\pgf@ya\pgf@y
    \advance\pgf@xa-\qrr@pgf@normcs@from@x
    \advance\pgf@ya-\qrr@pgf@normcs@from@y
    \pgfpointnormalised{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgf@yy*\pgf@x-\pgf@yx*\pgf@y}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{-\pgf@xy*\pgf@x+\pgf@xx*\pgf@y}
    \pgfmathatantwo{+\pgf@xa}{+\pgf@ya}
}
\def\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@unit#1{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#1)\relax
    \pgf@xa\pgf@x\pgf@ya\pgf@y
    \advance\pgf@xa-\qrr@pgf@normcs@from@x
    \advance\pgf@ya-\qrr@pgf@normcs@from@y
    \pgfpointnormalised{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfmathatantwo{+\pgf@x}{+\pgf@y}
}
\def\qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@@to#1{%
    \ifqrr@tikz@normcs@unitsdeclared
        \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@unit
    \else
        \ifx\qrr@next\relax
          \pgfutil@in@{cs:}{#1}%
          \ifpgfutil@in@
            \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@hard
          \else
            \pgfutil@in@{intersection }{#1}%
            \ifpgfutil@in@
              \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@hard
            \else
              \pgfutil@in@|{#1}%
              \ifpgfutil@in@
                \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@hard
              \else
                \pgfutil@in@:{#1}%
                \ifpgfutil@in@
                  \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@easy
                \else
                  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
                  \ifpgfutil@in@
                    \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@easy
                  \else
                    \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@normcs@calc@hard
                  \fi
                \fi
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    \begingroup
        \qrr@next{#1}%
        \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
    \endgroup
    \let\pgf@tempa\pgfmathresult
%   \pgfmathifthenelse{\pgf@tempa<0}{\pgf@tempa+180}{\pgf@tempa}%
%   \let\pgf@tempa\pgfmathresult
    \ifqrr@tikz@normcs@unitsdeclared
        \pgfpointpolar{\pgf@tempa}{\qrr@tikz@norm}%
    \else
        \pgfpointpolarxy{\pgf@tempa}{\qrr@tikz@norm}%
    \fi
}
\def\qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@from#1 from #2\@qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@from{%
    \def\qrr@tikz@normcs@parse@to{#1}%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#2)\relax
    \qrr@pgf@normcs@from@x\pgf@x
    \qrr@pgf@normcs@from@y\pgf@y
}
```

#### Example 1

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,norm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    gridded,
%   Norm=1cm,
%   x=-2cm,
%   x={(1.5cm,1cm)},
%   y={(-1.5cm,1cm)}
    ]

\draw (0,0)  coordinate[label=below:$O$] (O) circle (1);
\draw (1,3)  coordinate[label=right:$a$] (a) circle (1);
\draw (-2,5) coordinate[label=left:$b$] (b) circle (1);

\draw (O) -- (b);\draw (O) -- (a);\draw (a) -- (b);

\tikzset{every path/.append style={green,thick}}
\path[->] (O)   edge ++(norm cs: b)
                edge ++(norm cs: a)
                ;
\path[->] (a)   edge[blue] ++(norm cs: b)
                edge[red]  ++(norm cs: a)
                edge[norm] (b) % equal to edge ++(norm cs: b from a)
                edge       ++(norm cs: O from a)
                ;

\path[->] (b)   edge[red]  ++(norm cs: b)
                edge[blue] ++(norm cs: a)
                edge       ++(norm cs: a from b)
                edge       ++(norm cs: O from b)
                ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here a way without calc. I used `\pgfpointnormalised` to get a vector with a width of 1pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter  
  \def\vectornormalised#1#2{%
\begingroup 
   \coordinate (tempa) at (#1);
   \coordinate (tempb) at (#2);
  \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{tempa}{center}}%
               {\pgfpointanchor{tempb}{center}}%
  \pgfpointnormalised{} 
  \pgf@xa=28.45274\pgf@x%
  \pgf@ya=28.45274\pgf@y% 
  \draw[red,->] (#1)-- +(\the\pgf@xa,\the\pgf@ya) coordinate (tempc);
\endgroup
}

 \tikzset{norm/.style={to path={%
  \pgfextra{\vectornormalised{\tikztostart}{\tikztotarget}} (tempc) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
   }}}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,3);
\coordinate (a)  at (1,0);
\coordinate (b)  at (5,1);
\coordinate (c)  at (2,3);
\draw[blue,->] (a) to [norm] (b);
\draw[orange,->] (b) to[norm] (c);
\draw[green,->] (a)  to [norm] (c);
\draw (a) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]